# Using LCD Library with Johnny Five on Node Js and Arduino

Tags: node.js, arduino, lcd, johnny-five

I am trying to make my lcd turn it off the backlight and on again.

The command to turn it on: `lcd.noBacklight();` is working fine, but I don't know how to turn it on again.

```
var five = require("johnny-five");
var board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {

  var lcd = new five.LCD({
    controller: "PCF8574T"
  });

  lcd.cursor(0, 0).print("1 Hello Teste");
  lcd.cursor(1, 0).print("2 Hello Teste");
  lcd.cursor(2, 0).print("3 Hello Teste");
  lcd.cursor(3, 0).print("4 Hello Teste");

  lcd.noBacklight();

  setTimeout(() => {
    lcd.yesBacklight(); //Here I don't know what to do
  }, 1500);

  setInterval(() => {
    lcd.noBacklight();
  }, 1500);


});
```

How could I turn it on again?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved that just putting `lcd.backlight();` in lower case.

```
var five = require("johnny-five");
var board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {
  var i = 0;
  var lcd = new five.LCD({
    controller: "PCF8574T"
  });

  lcd.cursor(0, 0).print("1 Hello Teste");
  lcd.cursor(1, 0).print("2 Hello Teste");
  lcd.cursor(2, 0).print("3 Hello Teste");
  lcd.cursor(3, 0).print("4 Hello Teste");

  setInterval(() => {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.noBacklight();
    lcd.cursor(0, 0).print(i + " Hello Teste");
    i++;
    lcd.backlight();
  }, 1500);


});
```

Comment: What does the controller: "PCF8574T" mean?

Comment: It is the model of Adapter PCF8574T, the controller name is printed on the chip mounted on the read of the LCD backpack.
I made this https://www.instructables.com/id/Computer-Monitor-Using-Arduino/ using this code

Comment: Ok. Is it necessary to include that name in the code? How does it make a difference?

Comment: You can check Johnny Five wiki here: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/LCD
Each controller must be treated different because of the analogs and logical/ Inputs and Outputs. And naming it is the only way to this package handle this.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks. I do not see my controller name RG1602A in the wiki. Will this matter? The reason I am asking is that I am trying to print to my LCD from my node.js code but it wont print anything. I have created this Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965869/lcd-not-working-in-node-js-arduino-project?noredirect=1#comment74963758_43965869     I would appreciate if you can guide me to the right direction. I am very confused.