# LCD not working in node.js + Arduino project

Tags: node.js, arduino-uno, lcd, johnny-five

I am following [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-apis-on-arduino-lcd/) tutorial, but I am doing a very basic version where I just want to print something out.

All the pins and hardware specification are followed as per that tutorial.

Below is my **app.js** code:

```
var five = require('johnny-five');
var board = new five.Board();
var lcd;

board.on('ready', function() {
    lcd = new five.LCD({
        // LCD pin name  RS  EN  DB4 DB5 DB6 DB7
        // Arduino pin # 12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2
        pins: [12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2],
        rows: 2,
        cols: 16
    });

    lcd.clear().print("Hello NJ");

    this.repl.inject({
        lcd: lcd
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I connect my arduino to my laptop the lcd screen lits up, however when I run the code it does not show anything on the screen. I also followed [this](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/lcd.md) tutorial and the result is same.

Even if I remove the print command and do something like

```
lcd.noBacklight();
```

it does not work.

Even if I write the `lcd.print("hello world")` command in the console, it does not get printed on the lcd (however it does not show me any error on the console).

I have uploaded the Standard Firmata using my Arduino IDE. The johnny-five module works cause I tried their led examples and it was working.

Is my lcd device messed up or is it my code or is it my hardware connections?

I am confused.

Comment: Do you have the exact same LCD?

Comment: No I dont think so. None of the tutorials have mentioned what LCD they are using. I bought an Arduino starter kit off Amazon and it had this LCD as part of it.

Comment: A lot of these LCD's use a Toshiba chip (HD44780) to drive the screen, you should make sure that yours does as well (although I'd assume that because it's part of a starter kit, it will). Because the backlight lights up, the power seems to be connected properly, so next step is to check if all connections are correct (you won't get errors if they aren't, it just won't work). If you have a link to the starter kit on Amazon, please add it to your question, it may be useful. FWIW, the last tutorial you link to is using different pin connections, did you notice that?

Comment: Here is the amazon link: http://www.amazon.in/Robo-India-Arduino-Starter-Kit/dp/B01JI27XSW?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00       Yes the last tutorial uses a different pin connection and I tried that as well in hopes that maybe the first pin connections were incorrect.

Comment: The LCD chip is correct. Have you ruled out that the contrast is turned all the way down?

Comment: Ok so the potentiometer arrow is all the way down. Do i move it up? Here is the photo I took of my setup which shows the potentiometer:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B43t-lgy1BmXMTJ0a05jVExuLWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can just turn it while it's powered on, any way you like, see if it changes anything.

Comment: Moved the arrow clockwise and i can see black blocks on the lcd screen but still no printed text :(    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B43t-lgy1BmXd2FmV2N0N2x6dnc

Comment: Black blocks means the contrast is turned up too high. Looking at the code examples, the pin-set that you're using isn't critical (both examples _should_ work), as long as the pins in the code match the pins that are connected on the Arduino and also (very important) that they are in the correct order in the code (so it should be `[12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2]` and not `[2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12]` because sorting them makes the code look better).

Comment: In the code I posted above it is [12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2] I just double checked the connections and 12 = RS, 11 = E, 5 = D4, 4 = D5, 3 = D6, 2 = D7.  The Vo is connected to the forward pin of the potentiometer, the left pin to ground and right pin to 5v. So everything checks out. I am not sure where I am failing.

Comment: Yeah I'm kind of at a loss too :(